# Email not being sent with Swift Mailer using Gmail SMTP

Tags: php, email, gmail, swiftmailer

I am trying to send emails from Swift Mailer using Gmail SMTP. It sends the emails conveniently for some time but then stops sending them altogether especially when I resume working after a day or so. It displays the following error:

Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]

Below is my sample code that I am using to send the email:

```
<?php
    require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';
    try
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        //Generating the Email Content
        $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
                    ->setFrom(array('myemail@gmail.com' => 'No Reply'))
                    ->setTo(array('recipient@gmail.com' => 'Recipient'))
                    ->setSubject('Test Email')
                    ->setBody("This is a Test Email to check SwiftMailer.");

        // Create the Mail Transport Configuration
        $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl')
                    ->setUsername('myemail@gmail.com')
                    ->setPassword('appPassword');

        //local domain sending
        $transport->setLocalDomain('[127.0.0.1]');

        $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

        //Send the email
        $sentFlag = $mailer->send($message);
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

?>
```

I am using App Password and I have enabled two-step verification in my Google Account Settings. I have been looking for a solution to this problem for a while now and i have already gone through many other related posts but didn't find a solution. Someone please suggest a permanent solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to change ('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl') this to ('smtp.gmail.com', 587) . Let's see whats happening

Comment: Got this error: Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. j62sm11357963wmf.4 - gsmtp
"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to use Swift Mailer Using Gmail SMTP

Try this code like this:

```
<?php
    require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';
    try
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        //Generating the Email Content
        $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
                    ->setFrom(array('myemail@gmail.com' => 'No Reply'))
                    ->setTo(array('recipient@gmail.com' => 'Recipient'))
                    ->setSubject('Test Email')
                    ->setBody("This is a Test Email to check SwiftMailer.");

        // Create the Mail Transport Configuration
        $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 587, 'tls')
                    ->setUsername('myemail@gmail.com')
                    ->setPassword('appPassword')
                    ->setStreamOptions(array(
                     'ssl' => array(
                     'allow_self_signed' => true, 
                     'verify_peer' => false)));

        //local domain sending
        $transport->setLocalDomain('[127.0.0.1]');

        $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

        //Send the email
        $sentFlag = $mailer->send($message);
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

?>
```

*Hope it helps*

Comment: threw the error: Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in C:\wamp64\www\domain.com\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php on line 94

Comment: @JunaidFarooq I edited the code to allow turning off ssl cert. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, @LasVegasCoder. It did work but I was wondering if it would be safe to allow the connection without certification/peer verification. I am currently trying it on Localhost but I will be migrating it to the live server soon. I don't wanna have any security risks.

Comment: Once migrated to live server you can remove the option and allow certificate verification.   Don't forget to mark this answer as Accepted to help others.